# How to overcome the situation where a user leaves and nobody can change his elements in ClearCase

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

Currently we are restricted to using ClearCase remote client only (CCRC), as the native client is painfully slow and can't do anything with it.

THe problem is that files and branches are created by users using their corporate credentials, so as elements are created, the elements are owned by their respective creator.
When a developer leaves the company, nobody else can change their elements (for correcting errors etc.).
We are at a remote location and were not allowed to have "clearcase admin" priviledges.  The only clearcase admin is at our division headquarters. We don't want to have to call the corporate "admin" to do our daily work like correcting files owned by others, etc.

At my previous location, we solved this problem by having a "trigger" change the ownership of each element upon creation to a "fictitious" owner.  Only the chief engineer had the password for the "fictitious" owner, and could correct errors easily.  However, our clearcase server was localy placed.  Now our server is remotely located (therefore we need to use the remote client).

Could we setup the same triggers to work with our CCRC client?
Is there any other solution for this problem out there that works for remotely located groups?
THanks.

Answer (score 0):

> When a developer leaves the company, nobody else can change their elements (for correcting errors etc.).

They should, if they are from the same group than the one having modified the file.

The solution should be at least to change the group of any file with the wrong group, in order to set a group in which *all* users are declared.
That `cleartool` command is to be run on the CCRC server by an admin.

```
cleartool find . -exec "cleartool protect -chgrp \"ANewGroup\" \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
```